# Attach a file with different name

Tags: embedding, attachfile, embedfile

I would like to attach a file to a PDF document like `\attachfile` or `\textattachfile` does, but I want the attached file to be renamed. As far as I have seen, the packages `attachfile` and `attachfile2` do not provide this feature.

With the packages `embedfile` and `navigator` I could embed files and select new names for storage. But I would like to have an annotation inside my text like `\attachfile` does. Is there some working combination of both or some raw PDF wizadry to access the embedded files?

Here is an MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{foo.bar}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Foo.
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[color=red]{attachfile2}
\usepackage{embedfile}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item Attachment of the file 'foo.bar':
  \textattachfile{foo.bar}{Embedded file with original name}

\item Embedding of 'foo.bar' as 'usefulname.tex'.
  \embedfile[ucfilespec={usefulname.tex}]{foo.bar}

\item How to attach 'foo.bar' as 'usefulname.tex' and get an
  annotation on the page as in the first case?

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation of `attachfile2` mentions the option `ucfilespec` and it worked for me, but only if I didn't include the file also with the original name:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{foo.bar}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Foo.
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[color=red]{attachfile2}
\usepackage{embedfile}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item Attachment of the file 'foo.bar':
 % \textattachfile{foo.bar}{Embedded file with original name}

\item Embedding of 'foo.bar' as 'usefulname.tex'.
  \embedfile[ucfilespec={usefulname.tex}]{foo.bar}

\item How to attach 'foo.bar' as 'usefulname.tex' and get an
  annotation on the page as in the first case?
\textattachfile[ucfilespec={usefulname2.tex}]{foo.bar}{Embedded file with changed name}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's it. :-) This option slipped my attention when I searched the documentation for something like that.